# How to save YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD formated date/time in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

I am importing data from an Excel sheet through PHP. I want to store a date that is in this format **2013-10-10T06:25:00+00:00** in a MySQL database. What data type should column have? How can I manipulate the format into one that MySQL can use?

Comment: You should convert it to a MySQL compatible format and then store it in a DATETIME column.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found an answer:

```
$time_raw=strtotime($time_excel);
$time_mysql=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time_raw);
```

Then insert into a DATETIME column. If you want to export the data, do the same trick with date().

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i also want to save date part. For example, "+04:00" in the date 2013-10-10T06:25:00+04:00.

What column type i should keep in MySQL?

Comment: All the times are being converted to UTC, so there is no need for keeping them, if you need to, use another column

Comment: One liner for posterity: `$time_mysql=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time_excel));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class to get the date string and convert it into the required format, like so:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-10-10T06:25:00+00:00');
echo $datetime->format('Y-F-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
10-October-2013 06:25:00
```

Once you have the date, it should be easy to insert it into your database.

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/JeFDJPiw)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I am confuse as i also want to store the part after + as well. For example, i also want to save this part of date "+04:00", in date like: 2013-10-10T06:25:00+04:00

Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @user2366640: you can format the date string in any way you want. Check out the documentation for `date()` function for the available options.

Comment: sure, problem that i feel is not with formating date but to save the formated date in MySQL.

Comment: i mean, i also want to save the part of the date after + (that is +04:00) in 2013-10-10T06:25:00+04:00

Comment: how i can save that in MySQL?

Comment: @user2366640: Save it as `DATETIME`. See  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks again for bearing with me. I can surely save it as DATETIME format but isn't it i will not be able to save +04:00 part in date 2013-10-10T06:25:00?

Comment: @user2366640: I don't know where you're getting that extra part at the end, but the idea here is to convert your date string to a format MySQL understands. If you want to get the extra part at end too, consider using a string function like `substr()` and get the value, and then you can insert them into your database as normal (not sure if it's the best way though).